# Using my own crypto provider for Windows without signing it

Tags: c++, windows-7, cryptography, cryptoapi, cng

I am required to make my own realization of the crypto algorithm and make it available for Windows applications.I made a crypto provider library for working through CryptoAPI under the instruction (in the article Service Provider Cookbook), except for the signature (Note: Starting with Windows 8, it is no longer a requirement that CSPs must be signed.). A library that exporting the required set of functions is in System32. Entries in the registry are done. The software in Windows 10 under which the CSP was developed hangs. But in Windows 7 when there was no signature this application produced an error.

Did I miss a step in registering CSP for Win 10 or what else could be the problem?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:provider] tag because the description reads "DO NOT USE" and inserted C++ because in general these kinds of providers are written in that language (also according to the MS documentation). Hopefully that will get you some more exposure. Already voted up, that's the last thing I can do :)

Comment: In the old days during testing you replaced `advapi32.dll` with a Microsoft supplied copy that skipped the signature verification. The Microsoft replacement of `advapi32.dll` was signed so it avoided the signature problems. The same procedure was used for unsigned drivers, if I recall correctly. I don't know if Microsoft still uses that model.